# Need to create a batch file to keep on the desktop to empty a folder we keep files in temporarily

Tags: windows-xp

We do patient information at work, and we keep files in a folder we marked General Temp for files we keep while working on a report and then need to delete after.  My co-workers and I are not that computer literate and I know there's a way to delete all these files w/ just a double click of a program or file on a the desktop.  I've not had any computer programming since high school, and that was a long time ago.  Any help would be appreciated, just remember I'm computer dumb now!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood your question right. With this batch script written into a .bat file you can delete the content of the `tmpFolder` specified between the two double-quotes.
It is a little workaround to make the code easier: first the folder is deleted with all content and then a new is created.

```
SET tmpFolder=""       REM for example: SET tmpFolder="C:\User\user\Desktop\tmpfolder"
rd /s /q %tmpFolder%
mkdir %tmpFolder%
```

Just open notepad and save this code with the inserted `tmpFolder` var on the desktop. Important is the extension of the file: name it for example "deleteTmp.bat". Don't forget to change the filetype (under the textbox for entering the name) into "all (*.*)".

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a batch file like `cleanTemp.bat` with the following content:

```
@rd /s /q "\path\to\general\temp\folder" | mkdir \path\to\general\temp\folder
```

Of course, you need to replace the `\path\to\general\temp\folder` with the appropriate value. Once, you have this file created, you can double click on it to perform your task.

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch file with the following content:

```
del /q "C:\General Temp\*"
for /d %%x in ("C:\General Temp\*") do @rd /s /q "%%x"
```

replace `C:\General Temp` with the path to your folder if it is not correct.

This will keep your original folder intact, if you need it for some reason.

Create a batch file following this [tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Write-a-Batch-File)